# Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Ok, so I notice there are many people on stackoverflow getting this error, but most of them involve a bunch of jQuery stuff I haven't learned yet.  Anyway, I don't know what I could possibly be doing wrong here, but here's the code:
var playerAnswer;

```
var computer;
function getCompAnswer(){
var x = Math.random();
if(x >= 0 && x =< 0.333333333){computer = "Rock";}
if(x > 0.333333333 && x =< 0.666666666){computer = "Paper";}
if(x > 0.666666666 && x =< 1){computer = "Scissors";}
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Rock. Paper, Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body><form id="form-id">
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head><div class="formstyle">
Choose one: <br>
<input type="radio" id="rock" name="game" onClick="retrievePlayerData();">
Rock
<input type="radio" id="paper" name="game" onClick="retrievePlayerData();">
Paper
<input type="radio" id="scissors" name="game" onClick="retrievePlayerData();">
Scissors
</div>
</form>
<div id="play"></div>
<div class="scoreboard">
<table>
<tr>
<th> You
</th>
<th> The Computer
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="playScore">
</td>
<td id="compScore">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="gamemsg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that most of this is unfinished but I had to restart and I'm getting stuck here.  (Error is in line 5 of JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `=<` operator, use `<=` for "less than or equal".

[Comparison operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I forgot about that!